# Shows the wrong day

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I am trying to use a `Datetimepicker` with `Bootstrap`, but the problem is that the `Datetimepicker` shows me the wrong Date when I click on it.

For example:

Today we are Thursday the `09/04/2014`, but it shows me that we are `FRIDAY the 09/04/2014`.
It seems that the year is wrong because when I look in my Windows `callendar` this date `" FRIDAY the 09/04"` isn't in 2014 but in 2015!

Answer (score 0):

Time warp again?

I'm assuming two things from your question which make my answer possibly useless.

1. This is done on a android sdk.
2. You are virtually testing your app.

In saying that i'm thinking it might either be something to do with the system time on the virtual simulation or maybe something to do even with the datetimepicker itself as i have seen there are at least 3 other people at the moment experiencing similar problems with no answers posted yet.

Otherwise i would have to say look carefully through the source if you can get your hands on it if the settings for the system you are running your app on are perfectly fine.

I hope this answer helped mate good luck

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) . I am not running my datepicker in a android sdk and I am not virtually testing my app :)

Comment: Well fair enough, make sure you specify what system you are running this on because as it is, your question leaves alot to guessing